# Display fields when user selects particular value from combo box - Validation logic issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a combo box, and there are 2 values to be selected from it. either `Male` or `Female`. When user selects `Male` then another 2 textboxes gets displayed. Those 2 text box cann't be empty (as they are being validated).

The problem : When the user selects `Female`, the 2 textboxes discussed above is hidden, and I am not allowed to navigate to the next screen without filling some values to those 2 fields (because its being validated). How can i solve this?

My COde

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td align="left">
            <select id="gender" name="gender" onchange='genderfind(this.value);'>
            <option value="female">female</option>
            <option value="male">Male</option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td id="gb" style="display:none;"> <td>
            <input type="text" name="name" /></td>
<td align="left"><span id="msg_name"></span>&nbsp;</td>
 <td>
            <input type="text" name="lastname" /></td>
<td align="left"><span id="msg_lastname"></span>&nbsp;</td>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</body>
```

JQUERY

```
function validateStep() {

                var isValid = true;


                var un = $('#name').val();

                if (!un && un.length <= 0) {

                    isValid = false;

                    $('#msg_name').html('first name missing').show();

                } else {

                    $('#msg_name').html('').hide();

                }

                // validate password

                var l = $('#lastname').val();

                if (!l && l.length <= 0) {

                    isValid = false;

                    $('#msg_lastname').html('last name missing').show();

                } else {

                    $('#msg_lastname').html('').hide();

                }

                return isValid;

            }
```

///

```
<script>
function genderfind(val) {
            //alert(element);
            if (val == 'male' ) {
                document.getElementById('gb').style.display = 'block';
            } else {
                document.getElementById('gb').style.display = 'none';
            }

        }
</script>
```

Comment: Why not just wrap the validation in a condition to check for gender ==male?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After `isValid = true;` wrap the rest of the code just before `return isValid;` in an `if` loop `if(document.getElementById('gb').style.display == "block") { /*[ your validation]*/
}`

And your HTML code is incorrect. You cannot directly have a `td` inside another `td`. Its good practice if you put `span` or `div` or `p` or anyother element instead of the `td`'s inside `<td id="gb" style="display:none;">`.

Answer (score 1):

call `validateStep()` function only when the two fields are visible.

```
 if($('#msg_name').is(":visible")){
    validateStep ();
 })
```

Comment: Where should i add this method?

Comment: add it where you are calling your validateStep function in your script